The Million Pound Note: Different versions?
I just finished watching The Million Pound Note, an enjoyable 1954 comedy starring Gregory Peck based on a story by Mark Twain. I watched a version freely available on YouTube.
There is a plot detail though which I quite vividly remember but which did not appear in the movie:

 The love interest of Henry Adams (played by Gregory Peck),  Portia Lansdowne (played by Jane Griffiths) is actually the niece respectively stepdaughter of the two gentlemen who provided the million pound note to Adams; unbeknownst to him, she is aware of his situation.

This detail is part of the original story by Mark Twain. Of course, memory is fragile, and mine more than most; I may have read the story decades ago. Still, I have visual memories of a conversation in the living room between the two old gentlemen and Portia, and I think later her secret was revealed to Adams when the note was returned to them. My "visual memories" include his confusion and consternation  when he realizes that

 Portia is close to the two old gentlemen.

I think the detail adds to the story: In the version I watched, Portia's character is rather flat, her romantic interest in Adams seems unmotivated (if we ignore that he is played by a glorious Gregory Peck, that is). I also note that the movie length is consistently given as 91-92 minutes, but the YouTube video is only 84-85 minutes long. The missing minutes would suffice for the missing parts.
There was a BBC Sunday-Night Theatre production from 1950, but it is apparently lost.1
Therefore the question: Does there exist a longer version containing the mentioned detail? I cannot find any mention of it though.

1 Like most of the TV broadcasts of that time.
